# .htaccess allow certain ip with file exceptions for all others

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know it's a bit of a beginner question but tried several combinations and none work... here's what i need to achieve using .htaccess and .htpasswd

- I have a www.mysite.com/protected folder.
- By default, all ip's shouldn't see this folder and any other files inside it exists (basically they should be redirected to www.mysite.com)
- A certain IP (my external IP M.M.M.M) should be able to access that protected folder and be requested a username and password
- All ip's should be able to see some files inside the folder without being asked for password (www.mysite.com/protected/file1 and www.mysite.com/protected/file2)

I know the latter rule opens an exception on the first but that's how i need it (a general rule denying all and then whitelisting some files)

Thanks in advance for any help, been struggling with this for a bit now :(